# Text with absolute position over image

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an image where I need to add a tag to the right bottom corner.

When I pust it there, it's 4px below the image, no padding nor margin is there.

```css
.postImage {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.post img.thumbnail {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.commercial {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="postImage">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f00/fff">
  <span class="commercial">commercial</span>
</div>
```

What is the best way to fix it? I don't think

```
bottom: 4px;
```

is the right one.

Thank you

Comment: You could also use `<figure>` for the wrapper and `<figcaption>` for the caption as they are used for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default image tag take some extra space in bottom because it's inline element. Change it to `block` element to remove extra space

```
.thumbnail {
    display: block; /*inline-block, float:left etc..*/
}
```

```css
.postImage {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.post img.thumbnail {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.commercial {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="postImage">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f00/fff">
  <span class="commercial">commercial</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display: block;` to thumbnail class.

```css
.postImage {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.post img.thumbnail {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.commercial {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="postImage">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f00/fff">
  <span class="commercial">commercial</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not changing anything!

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: This didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.postImage {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.postImage img.thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.commercial {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="postImage">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f00/fff">
  <span class="commercial">commercial</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's true that `img` default display is `inline` and by changing to `display:block` that works, but if you `don't` want to `change display` then you can add `vertical-align:bottom` which aligns element to `bottom line` of `parent div` as below, and yes bottom:0 works fine as your .commercial is positioned as absolute.

```css
.postImage {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.post img.thumbnail {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.commercial {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
img{
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="postImage">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f00/fff">
  <span class="commercial">commercial</span>
</div>
```